# Controlling defined values during unit testing

Tags: c, unit-testing, c-preprocessor

I would like to know if it's possible to change an included header with a set of defined values as preprocessor directives for another one during testing.

I have a set of values defined in a header

```
//Accelconfig.h
#define sampling_rate 1 // It can be 1, 10 or 25

#ifndef accel_sample_rate
    #define accel_sample_rate 25 //default sampling 25Hz
#endif
#if accel_sample_rate == 1
    #define sampleRateBits LIS2DH12_BITS_ODR_1HZ
#elif accel_sample_rate == 10
    #define sampleRateBits LIS2DH12_BITS_ODR_10HZ
#elif accel_sample_rate == 25
    #define sampleRateBits LIS2DH12_BITS_ODR_25HZ
#else
    #define sampleRateBits LIS2DH12_BITS_ODR_25HZ //default if invalid parameter
#endif
```

That I use to do some calculations, like the dataset duration based on the number of samples and the sample duration. Currently, it's set to 1, but will be changed to other values later on.

I'm unit testing a function (with unity / ceedling) that does one of such calculations, and I would need to test a corner case that requires the value to be more than 1, but I don't want to change the value in the header and I would prefer to avoid `#ifdef TEST` clauses, as they don't provide much more control either. I was wondering if there's a way to change the header for another one `accel_config_test.h` that can have its values changed dynamically from the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you write you don't want to use `#ifdef TEST` and don't want to change the header in general, but rather redirect to some fake header.  So, what you can do is create another `Accelconfig.h` header, possibly in some subdirectory of your test folder (maybe a folder named `fakeincludes` or the like), and make sure that the compiler finds this include file earlier in the include path than the true `Accelconfig.h`.  This would require adjustments to your build setup for building the test executables.

To make the values then dynamically modifyable: Within your fake `Accelconfig.h` you have the option to turn `sampling_rate` and the other macros into variables, or #define them to be function calls or whatever you prefer to allow the value to be modified.  (If you even want to test the scenario that the values change during run time, function calls give you this flexibility.)

Comment: That's pretty much it. I found out that my test suit allows passing defines on a per-test basis, so I can control which tests have the fake header and which don't. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Joel, can you give some details on how you set this up? Thanks 

Comment: :defines: :<test_name>: - MACRO

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor works at compile time (actually, *before* compile time), so, you can't change any `#define` dynamically.

You could cheat, to some extent. For example, suppose your function is named `f()`, you could define it like:

```
#if !defined(suffix)
#define suffix
#endif
#define f(WHATEV) f##suffix(WHATEV) { /* here the actual content */ }
```

This "macro-function" would be using `sample_rate`, but not defining it. The header would also not include another header that defines `sample_rate`, but would expect that `sample_rate` is somehow, somewhere, already defined.

Now, your test would have a "preamble", like:

```
#define sampling_rate SOMETHING
#define suffix TEST1
#include "header_to_test.h"

void TEST1() { /*test using f(); */ }
```

This is just a sketch to illustrate the idea, there are a lot of "little things" to figure out. It's ugly, as most preprocessor hacks are, but, it does give you what you want here.

A better approach would be to have that constant not be a macro. With some experiments with code and compiler options, on modern compilers, you can get similar if not the same generated binary code.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to your question.

> I was wondering if there's a way to change the header for another one accel_config_test.h

You can do this by two methods

First modifying the `accelconfig.h` as below

```
#ifndef ACCELCONFIG_H
#define ACCELCONFIG_H

#ifdef TEST
#include "accelconfig_test.h"
#else
... // accel_sample_rate part


#endif
... // part of file which will not change under test

#endif //ACCELCONFIG_H
```

Second option is to replace the use of `accelconfig.h` with `accelconfig_test.h`

For this

- For every place the `accelconfig.h` is included you need to use `ifdef TEST` to change it to `accelconfig_test.h`
- the `..test.h` file should have all the macros, functions, variables etc that were there in the first header file.

> can have its values changed dynamically from the test.

This depends on the way that your macro `accel_sample_rate` is used in your code. If there is any way that you can make this a variable, then you can directly define `accel_sample_rate` as a variable in `accel_config_test.h` and modify it using your test platform.

If not, you can compile the code each time to get the modified values.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a test.c then do this:

```
#include "Accelconfig.h"
#undef sampling_rate
#define sampling_rate 10
```

This changes the value for `sampling_rate` in the local translation unit of your test to `10`, while preserving it in other files using the same header. So it allows a non-intrusive test and you don't have to change anything in the header.

Comment: hi, thanks for your help. The problem is that the code that I need to change is in another translation unit, so it's impossible to drive the changes from the test files, as the code under test is, as you pointer out, a different translation unit